# Making a 38 V-powered 100 µA current source without using a REF200 or equivalent

Tags: circuit-design, current-source

I am trying to create a current source producing up to 100 µA, which is powered by 38 V, and not using a REF200 (so discrete components, and others such as opamp or TL431). It should be able to have a load up to 10 kΩ.

I already designed some circuits doing this, but they have flaws.

---

My first idea was this one (where \$I_{out} =\frac{V_{ref}}{R_1}\$ and \$V_{ref} = 2.5 \text{ V}\$):

[image: first circuit]

But the output current flows in the wrong direction as it is a current sink. I don't know how to "reverse" it so it becomes a current source.

---

My second idea was based on the Widlar current source:

[image: second circuit based on widlar current source]

In this case, the output current \$I_{out}\$ is the solution to the equation (with \$V_T = 26\text{ mV}\$):

$$I_{out}=\frac{V_T}{R_2}\ln \left(\frac{I_1}{I_{out}} \right)$$

It works as expected, but it uses at least twice the amount of current than it outputs, and the equation is not very accurate at 38 V, as it is already an approximation.

---

Finally I tried this one (a Howland current source):

[image: third circuit base on howland current source]

With an opamp which can be powered by 38 V, and \$R = \frac{V_{cc}}{I_{out}}\$. But it is quite sensitive to the resistors having the same value, which means it can quickly change if the temperature fluctuates or if the resistors are not precise enough.

---

Do you have any idea how to make such a circuit (or to improve my designs)?

Comment: What is a purpose of current source, and what are the requirements for it? Are there additional power supplies? These answers will greatly help to give suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used a Howland current source, because my source also needed to be adjusted by an input voltage. The circuit I used is the following :
[image: Howland current source]

Where the output current is : \$I_{out}=\frac{R_b}{R_iR_a}V_{command}\$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward method that is pretty accurate and uses cheap and common components. As you can see, the output impedance is very high.

Temperature sensitivity is the main factor and that's largely due to the TL431 drift, about +/-0.15% over the temperature range -40°C to +100°C in this simulation, in line with 'typical' TL431 specs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A decent starting point would be the [LM334 current source](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf). It's a two-component solution: one 3-pin TO-92 part, one resistor (R1). The OUT node can slew at 0.1V/us = 1V/10us. The R1's value at 25C temperature is about 677 Ohms, as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxCfyq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current source above has an inherent temperature coefficient of about 0.34uA/C. To reduce this coefficient by a factor of at least 10x at room temperature, the following circuit would be used:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh29LF.png)</sup>

The R2/R1 ratio is about 10 for the 1N457 diode that has roughly a -2.5mV/C tempco at room temperature.

The ratio should be adjusted appropriately based on the tempco of the diode.

The initial value for R1 depends somewhat on the forward voltage of the diode used at the current produced - about 0.6V for 1N457 at 1mA, less at 100uA obviously.

For details of these calculations, see the [datasheet, page 8, section "Application as a Zero Temperature Coefficent Current Source"](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf) for details.

Since diodes have negative temperature coefficients, almost any PN or Schottky diode will work. You'd really want to measure the tempco and forward voltage on the diode type you're using, and use those values to calculate the resistors needed.

A discrete current source will work just as well or better, but it needs to be a bit more complex than a 2-transistor Widlar source. You'll want a cascoded source with base current compensation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9fG5m.png)</sup>

This design comes from [“Current mirror circuit with accurate mirror gain for low β transistors”](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/vlsi2/docs/Papers%20Done/2001-05-ISCAS-HC.pdf) by Chen, Whiteside and Geiger, and is a very accurate current source even with typical β mismatch. The current error when the load sweeps from 1 Ohm to 10k Ohm is ~0.1%, better if the Q1+Q2, Q3+Q4 and Q5+Q6 pairs are selected for a 5% β match within the pair.

When implementing this circuit, the transistor within each pair should be thermally bonded by e.g. gluing the TO-92 flats together, or by placing the SMT parts on a large shared copper area for the bases.

Q1+Q2 are the current mirror. Q3+Q4 cascode with Q1+Q2 to increase the output impedance of the current source. They could be removed if the load resistance variation will be small. Q5-Q7 redistribute the base currents of Q1-Q2 equally between the legs of the current source.

The paper above left out the bias connection for Q3+Q4 - it is an important detail to make this circuit work.

The performance is excellent even with fairly low-β transistors - as low as 25 (!).

At a high operating voltage - as in your application, the temperature stability is essentially independent of VBE of the transistors, and is concentrated in the tempco of R2, which should be a thin film 50ppm type. The load resistance (here depicted by AM1) can be anywhere between 0 Ohms and 10k Ohms.

The VBE tempco of the series connection of Q1+Q5 is -4mV/K. On top of 38V, that yields about -100ppm/K current tempco due to VBE. Metallic resistors have positive tempco. If R2 would be a 100ppm/K resistor, it would nicely compensate, to the first order, the negative VBE tempco, and stabilize the current. The tempco of typical resistors is not guaranteed, and typically you'd want to measure the resistance change of a particular resistor type and value across the temperature range of interest, and see how linear its tempco is, and what is its value. A separate PTC can also be used in a series-parallel combination with resistors to tweak the tempco.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer! I have one more question though : if I remove Q3 and Q4, where should I connect the base of Q6 ? Or should I remove it entirely ? Because in my simulations, if I remove it (or connect its base to Q1's), I get an output current greater than in the whole circuit, and I don't know where that comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an FET.

Here is an [app note](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70596/70596.pdf) on FET current sources.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFfBeJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>